# Using Views with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am looking at the Hibernate documentation 3.x for using views with Hibernate : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class

The document says:

> Sometimes you want to use a view, but you cannot create one in the
>   database (i.e. with a legacy schema). In this case, you can map an
>   immutable and read-only entity to a given SQL subselect expression:

```
<class name="Summary">
    <subselect>
        select item.name, max(bid.amount), count(*)
        from item
        join bid on bid.item_id = item.id
        group by item.name
    </subselect>
    <synchronize table="item"/>
    <synchronize table="bid"/>
    <id name="name"/>
    ...
</class>
```

Can you please help me in understanding this, how the Java file for Summary looks like? When we need to use the synchronize tags inside class tags and what is the purpose of it?

Also what is the meaning for below statement:

> Declare the tables to synchronize this entity with, ensuring that
>   auto-flush happens correctly and that queries against the derived
>   entity do not return stale data. The  is available both as
>   an attribute and a nested mapping element.

Answer (score 0):

You can just map as nomal class, like this:

```
<class name="Summary">
<subselect>
    select item.name, max(bid.amount) as amount, count(*) as qtt
    from item
    join bid on bid.item_id = item.id
    group by item.name
</subselect>
<synchronize table="item"/>
<synchronize table="bid"/>
<id name="name" column="name" type="java.lang.String"/>
<property name="amount" column="amount" type="java.lang.Double" />
<properyt name="qty" column="qty" type="java.lang.Integer" />
```

and then define the class

```
public class Summary{
  private String name;
  private Double amount;
  private Integer qty;
  //...setter/getter
}
```